# Is there a way to backup periodically Users Table and Roles via code in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Unfortunately, I've buyed an hosting that doesn't allow me to update the database using Migrations of Entity Framework. (Don't ask me why, 70€ per year and their service is the worst i've ever seen)
If i make changes locally then i have to:

- apply changes locally (Add-Migration, Update-Database)
- backup my local db (Open SQL Server Management Studio and Backup)
- restore them in the server db in order to make changes effective.
   (Open Hosting Database and follow procedure to restore)

This procedure is risky, becouse if i accidently forget to backup Users tables on Hosting side, i'll remove all the users causing many problems.
I would like to know if there's a way to backup DB Users Table and Roles from code periodically.

Comment: That's probably the worst hosting provider I've seen. Unfortunately, no, there's nothing built-in for backups like this.You could create a console application that performs the backup and periodically execute it

Comment: that's a really big problem :/

Comment: You can prevent this by moving the tables to another database and use seperate contexts. In that case you'll have one context for your business model and one for the security model. Or is there a limit on the number of databases as well?